# Asynchronous Ajax, what are the details of what's going on?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

This is an example from Trevor Burnham's Async JavaScript:

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
ajaxRequest.open('GET', url);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
while (ajaxRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT) {
// readyState can't change until the loop returns
};
```

Here's my understanding of what the example intends to teach: the `open` and `send` calls are asynchronous, so although the call to `open` queues a `readystatechange` event, it can't be handled until the while loop returns, so `readyState` can't change and this program will just hang in an infinite loop.

Here's my confusion: after looking at the W3C spec for the `open` method (http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-open), it looks to me that the algorithm for invoking `open` stipulates that a `readystatechange` should be fired at step 15. So given the above code, the loop will return since at the point of its execution, `readyState` is actually `XMLHttpRequest.OPENED`. What would actually make the program hang is:

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
ajaxRequest.open('GET', url);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
while (ajaxRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.OPENED) {
// readyState can't change until the loop returns
};
```

My question: is this correction correct? Also, is `open` also asynchronous or just `send`? It seems like `open` must be synchronous in order for it to change the `readyState` before the loop is entered in the original example. That would make sense to me since all it's doing is set a bunch of attributes.

Comment: the whole object's methods are sync, as is every objects. don't use while in an ajax call, there is absolutely no good reason to do so.

Comment: What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: why are you using while loop like that? xmlhttprequest has events.

Comment: @dandavis: How are every object's methods synchronous? Clearly, send is not synchronous.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: I wanted to know if my understanding was correct and additionally, if open is synchronous while send is asynchronous. In many articles about Ajax, it's explained that "Ajax is asynchronous by default" without going into the details of what that means.

Comment: @Ejay: The first line explains that the example was taken from a book.

Comment: because js code runs in a single thread thread, all js code, including object methods is technically synchronous. it might queue other side-effects in the background before returning, but a method "has the mic" until it returns or runs out of function body. unless you explicitly defer action sync's the the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this correction correct?

Yes, it is. The `open` method, whose specification you have linked, does set the `readyState` to `OPEN` synchronously. You can test this by simply logging the property value before and after you've called the method. The first loop (with the `readyState === UNSENT`) will simply break and not even enter the body, only your corrected one will produce an infinite loop.

> Also, is open also asynchronous or just send?

(Assuming an asynchronous request). Both methods return immediately.

`open` does set the readystate to `OPENED` synchronously. It also synchronously dispatches a `readystatechange` event immediately after that (before it returns).

`send` does set the `sent` flag to true synchronously. There is no "SENT" readystate, so it does not fire an event for that. It does however fire a `loadstart` progess event (before it returns).

When the response is asynchronously received, tasks are queued in the event loop to [switch the readystate](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#switch-headers-received) again; these events will be asynchronous.